# Can I recover a deleted file that was never committed?

Tags: file, svn, delete-file, recover

I added a directory to a repository but did not commit the change. Then I removed it, not realizing it would delete the entire directory. To be clear this is exactly what I did:

```
svn add directory/
svn remove directory/ --force
```

Is there any way to recover the file or am I SOL?

P.S. Who the hell decided SVN should have two different commands `delete` and `remove` that do the exact same thing?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way, through svn, to recover a file that was not committed to svn.

Comment: Yeah it's looking like that. However I ran into a little luck - I still had most of the code open on another computer and was able to recover almost the whole folder. Phew...